# an adjective after a noun

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives

I have faced the following
sentence:

"The work leverages features unique to a particular platform."

As far as I know an adjective is used before a noun but how can we say "features unique"?

I think "unique features" is correct. But this sentence is written in a valid text and the probability of making a mistake by authors is very low!!!

Comment: Adjectives can come after a noun. In the quoted sentence, the prepositional phrase "to a particular platform" is attached to the adjective "unique". An adjective that is connected to a prepositional phrase cannot come before a noun: we can't say "unique to a particular platform features". So the adjective and the prepositional phrase are both put after the noun in this situation.

Comment: Most adjectives that have an obligatory complement can only occur after the noun they modify. In your example "to a particular platform" is such a complement, and hence "unique to a particular platform" is an adjective phrase directly post-modifying "features".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example sentence is an elided form of the following:

> The work leverages features ***[that are]*** unique to a particular platform.

In short, it's assumed to have a relative pronoun and verb between *features* and *unique*. But it's not uncommon to leave those linking words out.